# How to pass a value to ng-container ngTemplateOutlet

Tags: angular

I'm mastering angular directive and I'd like
to pass a value to my component my code:

My component

```
`
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-one',
  template: `
    <ng-container
      *ngTemplateOutlet="layoutTemplate; context: { name: name }"
    ></ng-container>
  `
})
export class MyOneComponent {
  @ContentChild(TemplateRef, { static: true })
  @Input()
  layoutTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
}
`
```

and in app.component.html

```
`@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <app-my-one>
      <ng-template let-name="current">
        <span>Ahoj {{ name }}!</span>
      </ng-template>
    </app-my-one>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  current = 'Svet';
}`
```

But I can only see 'Ahoj'

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

try this way by pass the context object to the `MyOneComponent`

*MyOneComponent template*

```
<ng-container
  *ngTemplateOutlet="layoutTemplate;context:myContext"
></ng-container>
```

*App Component template*

```
<app-my-one [myContext]="current" >

  <ng-template let-name="name">
    <span>Ahoj {{ name }}!</span>
  </ng-template>

</app-my-one>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-axsrc1)

[doc : NgTemplateOutlet](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet)

Comment: Thanks for the hint but I'm lokking a way to pass the value without using an extra Input.

Comment: this can be done if you get bin the variables with the parent variable this mean you don't use `let-variablename`

Comment: check this demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-em8rfx is this what you want ? @user3887366

Comment: I'd like to pass it by let-name